# Create two nodes on a Elasticsearch run as a service

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using *one single Linux machine* and I'm running **Elasticsearch as a *service*** (I run ES with the command `service elasticsearch start`). My configuration has only one node so I would like to add to my cluster a new node (as a [failover](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_add_failover.html)) to locate the replicas there.

I'm trying to follow the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26162690/run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-as-a-service-on-one-ubuntu-server) question but the solutions are super messy and I can't find any way to archieve my goal.

Can someone explain me (in the most clear way as I'm quite a newbye in Linux) what do I've to do to add a new node to my Elasticsearch?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to terminal and run `elastic search` instance again.
Your new node will be set up.You can run as many instances as you want.

Comment: As I stated on the post it's running *as a service*, no instances. So if I run again the command `service elasticsearch start` it states that it's `already running`

Comment: Go to the directory where `elasticsearch` is there. Then go to `bin` and run `./elasticsearch`.

Comment: Do I have to change something in `elasticsearch.yml` file?

Comment: When I run `./bin/elasticsearch` nothing happens (it seems it's working as no error is showing on the logs). If I run `curl 'myip:9200'` I still see only one node.

Comment: have you tried running it twice on different terminals?

Comment: Yes. When i run the new instance `./bin/elasticsearch` the terminal gets stucked (I dont know if it's normal), so I've to open a new terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105235/discussion-between-richa-and-borja).

Comment: Some more useful information when running multiple nodes on a single machine: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elaticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67 , i.e. **make sure that each node has its own logs, config and data folder** or you'll get into all sorts of troubles.